# woocommerce password reset will empty cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, change-password

Is it normal that if I reset my password and then login again to the store it will empty my cart?
These are steps I have taken:

- Login to the woocommerce store
- add a product to the cart
- logout from the store
- reset my password
- login again to the store with the new password
- the cart is now empty.
  I believe that it is the password rest that triggers the cart to be emptied.  Why does it work this way? I suppose it is a security issue.
  If I don't reset my password and logout and then login again, the cart will contain the product I previously added. This is fine.

Just wondering why the password rest will empty the cart.

Comment: it is probably clearing the WC session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Just wondering why the password rest will empty the cart.*

This is normal behaviour. like Ozgur said, the user session is "cleared" upon resetting the password.

> *Why does it work this way? I suppose it is a security issue.*

It is indeed a security based behaviour. If you want to learn/understand a bit more about what is happening, you can take a look at what are Nonces.

*Source @ https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces.*

**To get around that behaviour and remain secure:**

- You could save the user cart info as a cookie/LocalStorage (JS based solution) (*More @ https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp*) and save the product ID that are in the user cart...
- You could also save it as a user metadata (PHP based solution) and serve it back to the user in that specific case.
- You could for example, when the user log back in, present him a popup window and a button to add all the items to his cart once more OR simply redirect him straight away to his cart by adding all the items. You can take a look at the link bellow to add products via url.

*Source @ https://gist.github.com/lukecav/ab9dbdee88de686ce6b59c264cde8970*